# correct ordering of array for numpy fast Fourier transform

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am trying to implement a simple version of the immersed boundary method for fluid-structure interactions in a periodic domain using the fast Fourier transform. This is done by first setting a force on the fluid, taking its FFT, solving a series of matrix equations, and taking the inverse FFT to recover the solution to the matrix system in the real domain. I am currently getting very strange results, and I think it might be because the solutions in Fourier space (u_hat, v_hat, p_hat) are not ordered correctly for the numpy ifft2 function, but I don't know how to fix that. I'd appreciate any help!

Edit: the idea is that given f, g, we want to find u, v, p. The algorithm is to take the fft in 2D of f and g, use that to compute the fft of u, v, and p, and then take the inverse fft to recover the real u, v, p. I've added the specific function relating f_hat, g_hat and u_hat, v_hat, p_hat.

Edit2: what I'd really like to know is how to order an arbitrary array so that it can be passed to the numpy ifft2 function, which requires the following: input should have the term for zero frequency in the low-order corner of the two axes, the positive frequency terms in the first half of these axes, the term for the Nyquist frequency in the middle of the axes and the negative frequency terms in the second half of both axes, in order of decreasingly negative frequency.

```
   N = 20   # Number of cartesian grid points
   l = 1.0     # Length of domain
   dx = l / N     # Grid step size
   mu = 8.9 * 10**(-4) 

   f_hat = np.fft.fft2(f)    # Fourier transform of x component of the force
   g_hat = np.fft.fft2(g)    # Fourier transform of y component of the force 

   u_hat = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=np.complex)
   v_hat = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=np.complex)
   p_hat = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=np.complex)
   
   for k in range(0, N):
       for m in range(0, N):
           if k == 0 and m == 0:
               u_hat[k,m] = 0.0
               v_hat[k,m] = 0.0 
               p_hat[k,m] = 0.0
           else:
               u_hat[k,m], v_hat[k,m], p_hat[k,m] = fluid_system(k, m, N, dx, mu, f_hat[k,m], g_hat[k,m])
   
   # Take inverse Fourier transform to get u and p  
   u = np.real((np.fft.ifft2(u_hat))).reshape((len(x),1))
   v = np.real((np.fft.ifft2(v_hat))).reshape((len(x),1))
   p = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(p_hat))

def fluid_system(l, m, N, h, mu, fft_f, fft_g):
   L = - 4.0 / (h**2) * ((np.sin(np.pi * l / N))**2 + (np.sin(np.pi * m / N))**2)
   D_l = - 1j / h * np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * l / N)
   D_m = - 1j / h * np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * m / N)
   A = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=np.complex)
   A[0,0] = mu * L
   A[0,2] = - D_l
   A[1,1] = mu * L
   A[1,2] = - D_m
   A[2,0] = D_l
   A[2,1] = D_m
   b = np.zeros((3,1), dtype=np.complex)
   b[0] = fft_f
   b[1] = fft_g
   res = (np.linalg.solve(A, b)).ravel()
   return res
```

Comment: We don’t know what you’re trying to do, what your expected output is, nor what your input data is. There is no way anyone here can help you. Please read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had given enough information, I hope the edits make it more clear.